# API Communication Bug -- Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am just starting to learn the Swift programming language and building a weather mobile application with Swift (UIKit). However, I am using non-Latin characters when communicating with the API, so I cannot establish proper communication.

When I convert the non-Latin characters in the city name to Latin characters and write them, it works properly.

For example, the name of the city I want to search for is "Eskişehir"

Eskişehir => its not working

Eskisehir => it works

When I paste the URL "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&appid=(apiKey)&q=eskişehir" into Chrome's address bar and press enter, it returns valid data to me. However, when I do the same thing using the simulator in Xcode, I cannot get any result.

I would appreciate it if you could help me. I'm leaving the code below:

```
//=====================View controller ==========

  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let city = searchText.text{
            weatherManager.fetchWeather(city)
        }
        searchText.text = ""
    }
    
    func weatherDataFetched(_ weatherDataModel: WeatherDataModel){
        tempLabel.text = weatherDataModel.tempString
        cityLabel.text = weatherDataModel.name
        weatherImage.image = UIImage(systemName: weatherDataModel.weatherStatus)
    }


//========================== Weather manager side=====================

  struct WeatherManager{
  static let apiKey = "bla bla bla"
  static let units = "metric"
  var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=\(units)&appid=\(apiKey)"

  var delegate : WeatherManagerDelegation?

  func fetchWeather(_ cityName:String){
        let fullUrl = "\(url)&q=\(cityName)"
        sendRequest(fullUrl)
    }
    
    func sendRequest(_ fullUrl: String){
        if let url = URL(string: fullUrl){
            let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let dataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                
                if  error != nil{
                    print("DataTask Error!")
                    return
                }
                
                if let checkedData = data{
                    if let weatherDataModel = self.parseJSON(weatherData: checkedData){
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.delegate?.weatherDataFetched(weatherDataModel)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
    
    func parseJSON(weatherData: Data) -> WeatherDataModel?{
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodedModel = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            let id = decodedModel.weather[0].id
            let temp = decodedModel.main.temp
            let name = decodedModel.name
            let weatherDataModel = WeatherDataModel(id: id, name: name, temp: temp)
            print(temp)
            return weatherDataModel
            
        } catch{
            print("Json parsing error")
            return nil
        }
        
    }
}


//===============Weather Data ================

struct WeatherData : Decodable{
    let name: String
    let main: Main
    let weather: [Weather]
}

struct Main : Decodable{
    let temp: Double
}

struct Weather : Decodable{
    let id: Int
}

//============== Weather Data Model =================
struct WeatherDataModel{
    
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let temp: Double
    
    var tempString: String{
        return String(format: "%.1f", temp)
    }
    
    var weatherStatus: String{
        switch id{
        case 200...299:
            return Constants.bolt
        case 300...399:
            return Constants.drizzle
        case 500...599:
            return Constants.rain
        case 600...699:
            return Constants.snow
        case 700...799:
            return Constants.fog
        case 800:
            return Constants.sun
        case 801...900:
            return Constants.bolt
        default:
            return Constants.cloud
        }
    }
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, temp: Double) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.temp = temp
    }
    
}
```

What are the reasons and solutions for this issue? If I want people to be able to search in their native language, would that be challenging for me? Or how can I ensure that they only use Latin characters?

Comment: Can you debug the error in the urlsession?

Comment: There is no error :(

Comment: `if let url = URL(string: fullUrl)` I think you don't pass that test, no? If you add a `else { print("\(fullURL) can't be converted to URL") }`, do you get into the `else`?

Comment: I added an else section and get an error. fullUrl cant converted to URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `fetchWeather` function's inner with

```
var fullUrl = "\(url)&q=\(cityName)"
fullUrl = fullUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
```

If you check the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding) you will see

```
Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all characters not in the specified set with percent-encoded characters.
```

This means that it converts characters that the url does not understand into a format that it can understand.

Url can't encode the character of `ş` thats why you are getting an error.

In the above code , keyword `Eskişehir` will be `Eski%C5%9Fehir`. The word `ş` will be `%C5%9` and url is in correct format now

Comment: Even though it works, it's contains a bug that could later cause problems. "URL encoding" is a very misleading term and leads to this kind of bug. URL encoding must only be used for encoding URL path elements and URL query parameters. It must not be applied to entire URLs. So the correct solution would be: `cityName = cityName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)! ⏎ var fullUrl = "\(url)&q=\(cityName)"`

Comment: I'd recommend to use `URLQueryItem` to be safe: ` var components = URLComponents(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"); components?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "units", value: units), URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: apiKey), URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: city)]; print(components?.url?.absoluteString)`